# for large enough $t_0 \ge 1$ we have $t \ge t_0 \implies \ln t \le \sqrt[2p]{t}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, proof-writing, logarithms

Why "for large enough $t_0 \ge 1$ we have $t \ge t_0 \implies \ln t \le \sqrt[2p]{t}$" is there an algebraic proof for this?

Comment: What do you actually understand by an "algebraic proof" here?

Comment: @trancelocation I meant not geometric one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using L'Hopital's rule we get
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\ln t}{\sqrt[2p]{t}} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\ln t}{t^{\frac1{2p}}} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^{-1}}{\frac1{2p}t^{\frac{1}{2p}-1}}= \lim_{t \to\infty} \frac{2p}{t^{\frac1{2p}}} = 0$$
since $2p > 0$.

Therefore there exists $t_0 \ge 1$ such that $t \ge t_0$ implies $\frac{\ln t}{\sqrt[2p]{t}} \le 1$, or $\ln t \le \sqrt[2p]{t}$.

Comment: I understand everything you wrote except for your last 2 lines why you are sure that there exists $t_{0} \geq 1$ such that .....? and what is the relation between this and $2p$ being greater than 0. could you provide more details please?

Comment: @Mathstupid It is just the definition of the limit. $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t) = 0$ means $$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists t_0 \in \mathbb{R})(\forall t \in \mathbb{R})(t \ge t_0 \implies |f(t)| < \varepsilon)$$ so I took $\varepsilon = 1$.

Comment: Also from where the condition $t \geq t_{0}$ comes and why $t_{0} \geq 1$?

Comment: @Mathstupid The limit gives us some $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $t \ge t_0 \implies |f(t)| < \varepsilon$. We can then pick $\max\{t_0, 1\}$ to obtain a number $\ge 1$ with the property $t \ge \max\{t_0, 1\} \implies |f(t)| < \varepsilon$. Then call this number $t_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the logs: this inequality is equivalent to
$$\ln(\ln t)<\frac1{2p}\ln t,$$
and setting $u=\ln t$, use that $\lim_{u\to+\infty}\dfrac{\ln u}{u}=0$, so for any $p$, there exists a $u_0$ such that 
$$\frac{\ln u}u<\frac1{2p}\iff \ln u<\frac1{2p}u\quad\forall u>u_0.$$
Translating this in terms of $t$, we obtain
$$\ln(\ln t)<\frac1{2p}\ln t=\ln\Bigl(t^{\tfrac1{2p}}\Bigr)\iff\ln t<t^{\tfrac1{2p}}$$
 for all $t>\mathrm e^{u_0}$.

Comment: why you are sure that there exists $u_{0}$ such that .....?  could you provide more details please?

Comment: That is because the limit is $0$: for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $u_0$ such that, for all $u>u_0$, …, and I chose $\varepsilon=\dfrac1{2p}$. Is it clearer?

Comment: yes it is thank you very much :)

Comment: And from where in the definition of the limit comes the part $u > u_{0}$?

Comment: It's the definition of the limit at $+\infty$: the finction can be made as small as we please, provided  $u$ is taken *large enough*.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The statement you are quoting can be rewritten as:

> There exists some $t_0$ such that we have $$t\geq t_0\implies \frac{\ln t}{t^q} < 0$$ (where $q=\frac{1}{2p}$).

very closely connected to the fact that, for all $s>0$, we have

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^s}{e^t} = 0.$$

Comment: How they are related?

Comment: @Mathstupid That, as books and teachers like to say, is best left as an exercise to the reader. They are connected via the exponential function, and some playing around with the equations is needed to see it, but it's there - and good practice, too!